# MongoDB: find document whose subdocument contains a given value

Tags: mongodb, find

Given is a Document like the following

```
{
    "type" : "sometype",
    "title" : "sometitle",
    "references":{
        "1": "someref",
        "2": "otherref",
        "3": ""
    }
}
```

How can I find all documents which have the reference `someref` set in the subdocument `references`?

A simple `find({references: "someref"})` doesn't work because references is not a valid array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document structure is not ideal for this kind of queries but you can use aggregation with [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$addFields: {refs: {$objectToArray: "$references"}}},
    {$match: {"refs.v": "someref"}},
    {$project:{refs: 0}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of subdocument fields you are looking into is small, then you can simply filter your collection using [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/index.html)

```
db.collection.find(
   { $or: [
            {"references.1": "someref"},
            {"references.2": "someref"},
            {"references.3": "someref"}
          ]} )
```